# java checkerboard pattern with asterisks

Tags: java

I've looked over lots of posts already and they have helped a lot, but none have covered my issue. I'm trying to print out an alternating checkerboard pattern for a class assignment. My output starting on the first line and every odd line has an extra print at the end. It should be repeating a 8x8 pattern basically. Here is my code and a screenshot of my output.

I need to know how to alter the code so that I only get 8 asterisks in the odd lines instead of the 9 that are showing now.

```
public class Checkerboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = 16;
        int height = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUsGu.jpg)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I apologize for that; I need to know how to alter the code so that I only get 8 asterisks in the odd lines instead of the 9 now.

Comment: @magusd Well, change your code to write fewer columns. You wrote it, so you should know which part of it determines that.

Comment: If I change the length variable down to 15 I only lose the blank space at the end which makes sense. If I lower it down to 14 I lose the entire last column. Since I'm using even numbers I'm not sure why I'm getting an odd output.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes and I get no errors or comments from Netbeans.

Comment: @magusd Do you know what ‘debugging’ means?

Comment: You have got a logical error up there. You are actually printing 9 times, but space character `(' ')` is not visible.

Comment: You should also give expected output.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I changed the last else statement to an else if with the condition j != length || i % 2 != 0 so now if it is an odd number row it will not print out an extra '*' at the end.

```
public class mainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int length = 15;
    int height = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else if (j != length || i % 2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although below snippet is not optimized, but it should work for you. There is scope of simplification. Try that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = 16;
    int height = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        char first = ' ';
        char second= '*';
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            first = '*';
            second = ' ';
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(first);
            } else {
                System.out.print(second);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```